# R Calculate date based on dates in sequential rows in a data frame

Tags: r, sapply

I have a data frame with a date column titled 'End_Date'. I want to add a new column 'Start_Date' that calculates the day after the previous 'End_Date'. For example:

```
End_Date <-as.Date(c("2010-11-01", "2010-11-18", "2010-11-26"))
dates <-data.frame(End_Date)
```

In this example, the new column 'Start Date' to look like this: 
    dates$Start_Date <-as.Date(c(NA, "2010-11-02", "2010-11-19"))

I have tried using sapply, but get an error stating that the new column has one too few rows:

```
dates$Start_Date <-sapply(2:nrow(dates), 
     function(i) (dates$End_Date[i]-dates$End_Date[i-1]))
```

Here, I created a data frame with only 3 rows just as an example, but I need to solution that I can apply to data frames with large numbers of rows.

Comment: `as.Date(c(NA, (end+1)[-length(end)]), origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: I created a data frame with only 3 rows for this example. But I will need to do this for a data frame with ~700 rows, so I am looking for some sort of loop or function for this

Comment: Why would you choose to loop it when you don't have to?  It doesn't matter how many rows there are. This is a vectorized operation

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies. Your first comment works for the example data frame, but when applied to a data frame with more rows as-is, I get an error like "replacement has 3 rows, data has 600". Perhaps it should be obvious how your commented code should be edited to apply to a larger data frame, but I can't figure it out. Also, if you have an answer, please provide it as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dates$Start_Date<-rep(as.Date(NA,origin = "1970-01-01"),nrow(dates))
for(i in 2:nrow(dates)) {dates$Start_Date[i]<- as.Date(dates$End_Date[i-1]+1)}
```

Or as Richard suggested in the comments, a much better method is:

```
dates$Start_Date<-as.Date(c(NA, (End_Date+1)[-length(End_Date)]), origin = "1970-01-01")
```